# docker tomcat with jmx

Tags: tomcat, docker, jmx

I'm trying to create a docker image with tomcat and JMX activated.

So I clone this tomcat docker image https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-tomcat. 
I exposed the port 1099 and edited the run script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f /.tomcat_admin_created ]; then
    /create_tomcat_admin_user.sh
fi

export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" 
exec ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh run
```

At the moment I don't really consider security, I just trying to have a JMX available.

Next a build the image `docker build -t <name>` and run it `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1099:1099 <name>`

Container is correctly launched and port forward: `0.0.0.0:1099->1099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`

And port is open `telnet 192.168.59.103 1099`. I use `192.168.59.103` because I'm on macos with boot2docker, and `192.168.59.103` is `boot2docker ip`.

But when I'm trying to connect to JMX via jconsole I get a timeout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

I must declare `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.59.103`

Comment: That's because you use Boot2docker.